# Mongo error when updating: cannot use the part to traverse the element

Tags: json, database, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I am attempting to update my mongo collection with the following structure

```
{
    "_id" : "T6GqWsi9qSxnyGzgC",
    "spec_name" : "test",
    "version" : "test",
    "message_type" : "test",
    "message_trigger" : "test",
    "segments" : [
        {
            "segment_id" : "MSH",
            "sequences" : [
                {
                    "dataType" : "ST",
                    "optionality" : "R",
                    "name" : "Field Seperator"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "ST",
                    "optionality" : "R",
                    "name" : "Encoding Characters"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "HD",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Sending Application"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "HD",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Sending Facility"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "HD",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Receiving Application"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "HD",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Receiving Facility"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "TS",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Data/Time Of Message"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "ST",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Security"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "CM",
                    "optionality" : "R",
                    "name" : "Message Type"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "ST",
                    "optionality" : "R",
                    "name" : "Message Control ID"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "PT",
                    "optionality" : "R",
                    "name" : "Processing ID"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "NM",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Sequence ID"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "ST",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Continuation Pointer"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "ID",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Accept Acknowledgment Type"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "ID",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Application Acknowledgment Type"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "ID",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Country Code"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "ID",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Character Set"
                },
                {
                    "dataType" : "CE",
                    "optionality" : "O",
                    "name" : "Principal Language Of Message"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "segment_groups" : [
        {
            "grouping_id" : 692335,
            "segments" : [
                {
                    "segment_id" : "test",
                    "group_segment_id" : 597268,
                    "sequences" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to append { value_one: "value", value_two: "value" } into the sequences array within segment_groups. My query looks like this:

```
db.messages.update({"segment_groups.segments.group_segment_id": 597268},{$push:{ "segment_groups.segments.$.sequences":{"value_one":"value", "value_two":"value"}}})
```

when attempting this i get the error:

```
"code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (segment_groups of segment_groups.segments.0.sequences) to traverse the element ({segment_groups: [ { grouping_id: 692335, segments: [ { segment_id: \"test\", group_segment_id: 597268, sequences: [] } ] } ]})"
    enter code here
```

Ive been at this issue for a day now and have no come across any sound advice on how to resolve or how to restructure my collection. I am new to mongo and am not aware of best practices when structuring so any method needed to make this a better solution is valuable.

Comment: Which Mongo version ?

Comment: the version is 3.4.10

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to 3.6 ?

Answer (score 10):

The problem you have is that your model has two levels of nested arrays (`segments_groups` and `segments`) and Mongo is not able to figure out which items in that arrays needs to be updated.

In MongoDB 3.6 it's easy to fix that using [arrayFilters / positional filtered operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html). In your update path you specify placeholders that represent one particular item for each array and then you have to add matching conditions as `arrayFilters` to help MongoDB finding which item you want to update. In your case:

```
db.messages.update({"_id" : "T6GqWsi9qSxnyGzgC"}, 
    { $push: { "segment_groups.$[sg].segments.$[s].sequences": {"value_one":"value", "value_two":"value"} } }, 
    { arrayFilters: [ { "sg.grouping_id": 692335 }, { "s.group_segment_id": 597268 } ] })
```

So `$[sg]` is one particular `segment_group` and `$[s]` represents one segment.